# Calculate calculate $E(\frac{1}{\bar X})$, Var$(\frac{1}{\bar X})$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Consider n i.i.d. observations from a Poisson (λ) distribution.

Suppose $\bar X =\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$

How do I calculate Var$(\frac{1}{\bar X})$ or even $E(\frac{1}{\bar X})$ for that matter.

I know that $E(\frac{1}{\bar X})\ne \frac{1}{E(\bar X)}.$ Hence I'm stuck.

Comment: These do not exist since $P(\bar X=0)=P(X_1=\cdots=X_n=0)=P(X_1=0)^n\ne0$ (or rather, if you prefer this terminology, $E\left(\frac1{\bar X}\right)=+\infty$).

Comment: I infer $P(\bar X = 0)=e^{-\lambda n}\ne 0$. But I don't know how that relates to the above question?

Comment: Ha. If $P(Y=0)\ne0$ then $P(1/Y=+\infty)\ne0$ hence $E(1/Y)$ does not exist (except if $Y$ is almost surely nonnegative then one can declare that $E(1/Y)=+\infty$).

Comment: I don't get why the if then statement is true?

Comment: If $P(Y=0)\ne0$, say with $Y\geqslant0$ almost surely and $Y$ integer valued, then $$E\left(\frac1Y\right)=\frac10P(Y=0)+\frac11P(Y=1)+\frac12P(Y=2)+\cdots{}{}{}{}\geqslant+\infty{}{}{}{}\cdot P(Y=0)=+\infty.$$

Comment: If the distribution is Poisson then this is a trick question. If the distribution is exponential with rate $\lambda$, then it's a fairly common exercise and there's a good reason for interest in $E(1/\bar X)$.. Please check for sure. If it is exponential, then see `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711124/` and the discussion and link there.